# Execute CustomAction with elevated privileges in WiX (synchronously or with asyncWait)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We're changing our installer toolkit from NSIS to WiX and I want to use a `CustomAction` to uninstall older versions of our program if necessary. For that I need to call the old uninstaller with elevated privileges before the new components are installed.

I use the following in my WXS file:

```
    <CustomAction Id="RemoveLegacyProduct" Directory="ProgramFilesFolder" ExeCommand="[PROP_LEGACYUNINSTALLER]" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="asyncWait"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="RemoveLegacyProduct" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[PROP_LEGACYUNINSTALLER AND NOT REMOVE]]></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The problem that I currently have is that the `asyncWait` does not seem to work. My old uninstaller is started and before it is finished the installation already continues (it even ends before the uninstaller is done).

How can I create a custom action that is executed synchronously (or at least the installation waits until the action is finished)? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need return=ignore or check for the install to completely wait until that uninstall is over. Asyncwait means "wait at sequence end", so it waits for the uninstall to finish at the end of the execute sequence, so it runs in parallel with your install.

Comment: I tried all of those and none worked. The uninstaller is always run in parallel to my installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it had nothing to do with WiX but the old uninstaller that spawned a second process and then terminated. So my installer was (correctly) waiting for the process to finish but it was the wrong process.